# Fetch first key from firebase database with swift 4 using ChildAdded

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I'm trying to fetch the first key from my firebase database but for some reason nothing is being printed out. How can I get the first key from my firebase database using `.childAdded`

```
let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-message").child(uid).child(userId)
    userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
        print(first)
```

[image: Database node]

Comment: use if let condition inside `{ (snapshot) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot { guard let first = snapshot.children.allObjects.first as? DataSnapshot else { return }
        print(first)}` try something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in incredibly easy if you literally are asking how to only ever get the first child of a node. Here's how to only get the first child of a /users node

```
func getFirstChild() {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
    })
}
```

or

```
print(snapshot.key)
```

if you just want the key.

Or, if you want to use a query to do the same thing

```
func getFirstChildAgain() {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    let query = usersRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toFirst: 1)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The child_added event is typically used when retrieving a list of items from the database. Unlike value which returns the entire contents of the location, **child_added is triggered once for each existing child** and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data. For ordering purposes, it is also passed a second argument containing the key of the previous child.

From: [Read and Write Data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Per your requirements, this is possible in `.value` and `childAdded`.

```
var child_array = [String:String]
let userMessagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-message").child(uid).child(userId)
    userMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? String ?? "Empty String"
        let key = snapshot.key 
        child_array[key] = value;


        }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

then:

```
if let first = child_array.first?.key {
    print(first)  // First Key
}
```

> Big NOTE: child_added randomly collects this data, you should never use it to sort your data

Comment: The OP was asking how to get the *first* node under a parent node. While the end result may be that node, you've got to be careful with .childAdded as that iterates over all nodes, one at a time. Each one is then loaded in the array which is not really used. If there are a million child nodes, it will iterate over all of them before exiting, which could take a while and may overload the device. It also leaves the observer on that node, so if another node is added, the 1M +1 node, it will go back over that entire node again, providing the same result (and every time another child is added)

Comment: @Jay That’s true but also the op didn’t mention any heavy traffic